# Global stream in logging macro

Tags: c++, logging, macros, stream, global

I've got a multithread program using several files. To log errors and different information of my program, I actually use the following macro defined in a header file included in all others files:

```
#define LOGFILENAME ("log.txt")

#define  TRACE_LOG(msg) \
            do { \
                fstream logFile;\
                logFile.open (((string)LOGFILENAME).c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);\
                logFile << __FILE__<< "\t function:"<<__FUNCTION__<< "\t"<< " (line:  "<< __LINE__<< "): "<<msg <<endl;\
                logFile.close();\
            } while(0)
```

I want to modify thus function (without changing prototype) in order to not open/close the file at each writing. Then, I tried to write in a global stream during the program execution and then write the stream in an output text file at the end of the execution. I tried this:

```
static std::stringstream LOGSTRINGSTREAM(ios_base::out | ios_base::app);        //global variable in the header file
```

//the new TRACE_LOG function:

```
#define  TRACE_LOG(msg) \
            do { \
                LOGSTRINGSTREAM.seekp(0, std::ios::end);\
                LOGSTRINGSTREAM  << __FILE__<< "\t function:"<<__FUNCTION__<< "\t"<< " (line:  "<< __LINE__<< "): "<<msg <<endl;\
            } while(0)
```

//The function called at the end of the program execution to write stream in the file:

```
#define WRITE_LOG() \
        do { \
            fstream logFile;\
            logFile.open (((string)LOGFILENAME).c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);\
            logFile << LOGSTRINGSTREAM.str();\
            logFile.close();\
        } while(0)
```

When I execute my program with these modifications, the log.txt file is not filled in real time (as expected) but, at the end of the program execution, only the last message is written in the log.txt file.
I think there is a problem in the declaration of the global variable but I cannot fix it.
Thanks for your help.
Fred

Comment: I finally fix it by declaring the global variable in header file with extern and declaring it in main.cpp without extern word.

Comment: Post it as answer, then